# Function pointers - outside library, warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, function-pointers

With yours help I finally compiled a code with function pointers. But now I would like to do exact same thing but for functions which are from the "outside" library. typedef, arguments, compilation flags are 100% fine, I got this warning ONLY when I try to call a function from the outside library (when I wrote a function with the same prototype and tried to call it with this code it was just fine). Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libs/outlib.h"

typedef int (*VFUNCV)(int, double);

void call(int which, VFUNCV* fun, int a, double b)
{
    fun[which](a, b);
}

int main()
{
    VFUNCV fun[2] = {outlibfun1, outlibfun2};

    call(0, fun, 3, 4.5);
    return 0;
}
```

Warning:

```
funargs.c: In function ‘main’:
funargs.c:14:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
funargs.c:14:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘fun[0]’) [enabled by default]
funargs.c:14:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
funargs.c:14:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘fun[1]’) [enabled by default]
```

And 14th line:

```
VFUNCV fun[2] = {outlibfun1, outlibfun2};
```

Declaration of `outlibfun`: `int outlibfun1(int, double);`

**ANOTHER NOT-WORKING (WARNING) EXAMPLE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libs/outlibz2.h"

typedef unsigned char* (*VFUNCV)(const unsigned char *, unsigned long, unsigned char *);

void call(int which, VFUNCV* fun, const unsigned char *a, unsigned long b, unsigned char * c)
{
    fun[which](a, b, c);
}

int main()
{
    VFUNCV fun[2] = {outlibfun1};

    call(0, fun, "b", 3, "a");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of `outlibfun1` and `outlibfun2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function isn't declared in the same source and before assigning a function pointer you need an extern declaration like

```
extern int outlibfun1( int, double );
```

In your case you should have them in `libs/outlib.h`

Comment: after adding extern declaration I got this: `funargs.c:9:23: error: conflicting types for ‘outlibfun1’
libs/outlib.h:114:16: note: previous declaration of ‘outlibfun1’ was here`

Comment: What's line 9? Anyway the error shows that there is something wrong with the declaration of `outlibfun1()`.

Comment: I've looked for `MD4()` in 'my' header (from 0.9.8.a) and found the second parameter to be `size_t` instead of `unsigned long`. That's not neccessarily the same.

Comment: Well you initialize your array `TEST_HMAC_FUN fun1[2] = {EVP_sha1, EVP_md5}` but `EVP_sha1()` and `EVP_md5()` are `const EVP_MD *EVP_...(void)` ehich is completely different from `HMAC()` and your `typedef`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the outlibfun1/outlibfun2 do not share the same function signature.
You could provide their definitions in order to clarify things.